# Magento Project Deployment

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, deployment

I want to deploy my `magento 1.9` project on server.
I have done these steps:

1. Export DB and inmport it into new server
2. Change local.xml DB Connection repositories

I am facing the problem with url because when i call the project in browser it is redirect to my local project url.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Phpmyadmin. Go to table `core_config_data`

Change values to your site url for following path

> `web/unsecure/base_url`
>
> `web/secure/base_url`

Delete **var/cache** folder too